# Felidar Guardian exiling Soul Seizer

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I use [Felidar Guardian](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFelidar%20Guardian%5d) to exile a transformed [Soul Seizer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=242498) I control, does it return as the enchantment and is put in the graveyard, or is it returned as the creature [Soul Seizer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul%20Seizer%5d)?

I think exiling makes it lose all properties prior to the exiling, so it should return as the creature, shouldn't it?

Comment: If an aura like Ghastly Haunting enters the battlefield like that, it doesn't go to the graveyard, you actually attach it to a legal enchantment target. And if it doesn't have anything to attach to, it would stay in exile instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right: the [rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190612.txt) say

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule:

But being transformed or not is not listed among the exceptions.

So in exile it's no longer transformed, and it will return to the battlefield as a creature, as that is the 'normal' way for this object to enter the battlefield:

> 711.8. A double-faced card enters the battlefield with its front face up by default. If a spell or ability puts it onto the battlefield “transformed,” it enters the battlefield with its back face up.

Comment: I suggest quoting rule 711.8 as the rules reference for the last sentence.

Comment: Right, that certainly doesn't hurt ...